# How to add separate background to parts of text in a paragraph in CSS, as that in the pic I have shared

Tags: html, css

[image]

In the image refer to the city image, under the Black + White logo.
On the image there is some text and has transparent background separately for separate lines.

How do I do add this kind of background to the 3 different lines of the same paragraph without using `<span>` or any other html tags and by purely using css.

Comment: SO requires that you put the relevant parts of your code (in this case, some attempt to solve the problem) *here*. Please do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a structure like this:

```
<div class="header">
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

You'd target the element with CSS like so, applying a translucent color background, inline styling, and a line-height larger than the font size:

```
.header p {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    display: inline;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 36px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/2vtwxroo/)**

You can discover techniques like this for yourself using your browser's document inspector to examine any website.

Comment: I think you've missed the point of the (poor) question. This is about the "non-background" **between** the lines of text. Your technique does not address that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just need your separate lines of text to be `display: inline-block` and preferably have some `margin` around them.

For the text background transparency, you will need to make use of **Red-green-blue-alpha model (RGBa)**.  As defined on the *Mozilla Developer Network* :

> RGBa extends the RGB color model to include the alpha channel,
>   allowing specification of the opacity of a color.

Making use of the aforementioned ideas, this is how it would look :

```css
.container {
    background: transparent url('https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Nikon-D810-Image-Sample-6.jpg') top center no-repeat;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.container > div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
}

.text {
    background-color: rgba(31,31,31,0.55);
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="text">some slick phrase would go in here</div>
        <div class="text">to sum up what the business</div>
        <div class="text">actually does and stands for</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but see the OPs (poor) question. You've ignored the basic premise of a **single** paragraph.